# Death loop, maybe it's the scanf

Tags: c, loops, scanf

```
scanf("%d", &jogadores[pos].dados[4][2]);
while (jogadores[pos].dados[4][2] < 0) {
    printf("O valor não pode ser menor que 0, introduz novamente: ");
    scanf("%d", &jogadores[pos].dados[4][2]);
};
```

Do you know what is wrong is this piece of code, I think it skips the first `scanf` because it keeps printing `O valor não pode ser menor que 0, introduz novamente:`

Comment: My guess, this is your problem.
&jogadores[pos].dados[4][2]

Comment: Always check the function return value from `scanf`. Here, it should be `1`.

Comment: @TonyTannous: we do not know the type of `jogadores[pos].dados[4][2]`, but if it is an `int`, the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @chqrlie
He only gave us 4 code lines. In these 4 code lines there is nothing suspicious besides the address that he is saving to and reading from.

Comment: @TonyTannous: yes there is! on 2 of these 4 lines, he fails to test the return value of `scanf`.  That's where the cause of the erroneous behavior lies, eg infinite loop. The fix takes more than 4 lines, but invokes `scanf` only once.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot check `scanf` success at parsing input by inspecting the output variables, you must compare the return value to the expected number conversions.  Furthermore, if the conversion fails, the offending characters stay in the input stream, so calling `scanf` again without first reading them will fail again, and again...

Here is how to fix the code:

```
for (;;) {
    if (scanf("%d", &jogadores[pos].dados[4][2]) != 1) {
        int c;
        while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
            continue;
        if (c == EOF) {
            printf("unexpected end of file\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAIL);
        }
        printf("invalid input, try again (non falo brasileiro)\n");
        continue;
    }
    if (jogadores[pos].dados[4][2] < 0) {
        printf("O valor não pode ser menor que 0, introduz novamente: ");
        continue;
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: A trouble is that unless `scanf("%d", &jogadores[pos].dados[4][2])` returns 1, the value in `jogadores[pos].dados[4][2]` is not known to be valid.

Comment: @chux: if `scanf` returns anything else, the loop is restarted.  look at the first test.

Comment: True'  The `continue;` does that.